# IIS is serving a Javascript file 146KB of 297KB and then stopping. Never Finishing

Tags: iis, coldfusion

This keeps happening with this one file, no other files, of course no other files are this big.

Why does IIS keeping stopping half way? I checked on the server there are no IIS errors and the server's performance is fine, CPU memory all look good.

The server is IIS and Coldfusion

Comment: Sounds like a sysadmin config issue to me. You'll have better luck on http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: Is this happening is all browser types?

Comment: How are you measuring this?  For example, if you are measuring raw bytes delivered, is it possible the file is being GZIPed?  Or are there clearly contents missing?

Comment: It is happening with all browsers. I'm using Firefox Firebug which shows it stop half way. Also Safari's web developer console. GZIP is not turned on in IIS.

Comment: As sdolan says, this'd be better on ServerFault, but a couple of debug suggestions: create other files (both .js and non-js) that are larger than 146KB and see if it behaves differently, And if possible, check from a different machine/network too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File might be damaged. Did you try deleting it and using a different copy?